# PHP validate file_exists in .m3u file

Tags: php, file-exists, m3u

I have a .m3u file, and I'm trying to validate each line to validate `file_exists` on the path.
Here's a single line:

`/home/scott/Music/Whitesnake/Whitesnake (30th anniversary edition)/1-01 Still of the Night.mp3`

My code looks correct, but the script is not working as I have validated the files exist. I've googled, gaggled, Stacked' and smacked, and I'm coming up empty for a solution.

Thank you in advance for teaching me...

```
$Jarvis  = new JarvisAPI(); // my api helper class
$m3uFile = $Jarvis->loadMainList();

array_shift( $m3uFile ); // lose the first line 

echo $Jarvis->getCount( $m3uFile ) . ' songs in list.<br/>'; 

foreach( $m3uFile as $idx => $filenamepath )
{
   if(file_exists($filenamepath)){
       echo "Exists - ";
   }else{
       echo "Not found - ";
   }

   echo $filenamepath;         
   echo "<br/>";
}
```

Sample results:

```
1116 songs in list.
Not found - /home/scott/Music/Whitesnake/Whitesnake (30th anniversary edition)/1-01 Still of the Night.mp3
Not found - /home/scott/Music/Bob Marley - The Very Best Of Bob Marley & The Wailers(2001)/Bob Marley & The Wailers - Get Up, Stand Up.mp3
Not found - /home/scott/Music/CAKE/Unknown Album/Sheep Go To Heaven.mp3
```

When I try hardcoding a path, it works, though:

```
$sample = '/home/scott/Music/Whitesnake/Whitesnake (30th anniversary edition)/1-01 Still of the Night.mp3';

if (file_exists($sample) ) echo filesize($sample);
```

outputs: 11736600

Comment: How are you running the PHP script? Via CLI or a webserver? It looks like a permission problem.

Comment: Where are the mp3 files in relation to the webserver root? Are they within the document root or somewhere else in the filesystem?

Comment: PHP script is running at `/var/www/html` on localhost. Music files (.mp3, .flac) are located at `/home/scott/Music` directory on same box.

Comment: PHP script runs via webserver, localhost LAMP on ubuntu.

Comment: `JarvisAPI` sounds like some Iron man stuff.

Comment: @nice_dev - yes, I like to use Marvel for many of my classes :)

Comment: Why did I get a -1 on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon a Windows system with `mp3` files located on the C drive and using the following `m3u` playlist file contents as `playlist.m3u`

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:261,Lou Reed & Metallica - Brandenburg Gate
\data\Archives\Music\Rips\Lou Reed & Metallica - Lulu [Disc 1]\01 - Lou Reed & Metallica - Brandenburg Gate.mp3
#EXTINF:320,Lou Reed & Metallica - The View
\data\Archives\Music\Rips\Lou Reed & Metallica - Lulu [Disc 1]\02 - Lou Reed & Metallica - The View.mp3
#EXTINF:444,Lou Reed & Metallica - Pumping Blood
\data\Archives\Music\Rips\Lou Reed & Metallica - Lulu [Disc 1]\03 - Lou Reed & Metallica - Pumping Blood.mp3
#EXTINF:412,Lou Reed & Metallica - Mistress Dread
\data\Archives\Music\Rips\Lou Reed & Metallica - Lulu [Disc 1]\04 - Lou Reed & Metallica - Mistress Dread.mp3
#EXTINF:277,Lou Reed & Metallica - Iced Honey
\data\Archives\Music\Rips\Lou Reed & Metallica - Lulu [Disc 1]\05 - Lou Reed & Metallica - Iced Honey.mp3
#EXTINF:686,Lou Reed & Metallica - Cheat On Me
\data\Archives\Music\Rips\Lou Reed & Metallica - Lulu [Disc 1]\06 - Lou Reed & Metallica - Cheat On Me.mp3



<?php

    $root='c:';
    
    $file=__DIR__ . '/playlist.m3u';
    
    $lines=file( $file );
    
    for( $i=2; $i < count( $lines ); $i+=2 ){
        
        $line=$lines[ $i ];
        $path=trim( $root . $line );
        
        printf( '<div>%s</div>', file_exists( $path ) ? sprintf('The file "%s" does exist!!!',basename($path)) : sprintf('Bogus - the file "%s" cannot be found',basename($path)) );
    }
?>
```

This generated the following:

[image]

Without using `trim` on the `$path` variable this failed so you perhaps should try removing trailing spaces from your `$filenamepath` variable?!

Comment: That's too damned easy! Thank you!!! I KNEW it was something simple.

Comment: :-) glad I managed to shed some light on this for you..